# Scala: Map Option[String] in tuple of Form Data and access it

Tags: forms, scala, tuples, type-conversion

I am using **Scala Forms**. I have set a keys and values in **Form Data** that is enclosed into a **tuple** having **String** as data type.

```
val userForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "k1" -> optional(v1),
      "k2" -> optional(v2),
      "k3" -> optional(v3)
    )
  )
```

and access this **Form values** using

```
val (k1, k2, k3) = userForm.bindFromRequest.get
```

It is working fine.

What I need is that. I want to make **k2** and **k3** keys as **Option[String]** type and **k1** as normal **String** type. So, when I place **Option[String]** to **k2, k3** keys.

```
 val userForm = Form(
        tuple(
          "k1" -> optional(v1),
          "k2" -> Some(optional(v2)),
          "k3" -> Some(optional(v3))
        )
      )
```

It throws error -

```
type mismatch;
 found   : (String, Some[play.api.data.Mapping[Option[String]]])
 required: (String, play.api.data.Mapping[?])
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Doesn't optional(v1) bind to an Option[String] like in Play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala-Form provides you a way of making it so that you can have `Option` values via using its `optional` field type.

So... when you declare a form as,

```
val userForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "k1" -> optional(text),
    "k2" -> optional(text),
    "k3" -> optional(text)
  )
)
```

Then, the `userForm` already declares the values `k1`, `k2` and `k3` to be `Option[String]`.

So to have it your needed way, declare the form with `k1` as normal `text` and others as `option(text)`

```
val userForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "k1" -> text,
    "k2" -> optional(text),
    "k3" -> optional(text)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A form mapping can also define optional values using Forms.optional:

```
case class UserOptionalData(name: String, email: Option[String])
val userFormOptional = Form(
  mapping(
    "name" -> text,
    "email" -> optional(email)
  )(UserOptionalData.apply)(UserOptionalData.unapply)
) //example taken from play docs
```

This maps to an Option[A] in output, which is None if no form value is found.

Change `k1` from optional to text to make it a compulsory field. Make `k1` text

```
val userForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "k1" -> text,
      "k2" -> Some(optional(text)),
      "k3" -> Some(optional(text))
    )
  )
```